# Pronto-Rubocop on Gitlab is not working, wrong URL being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, gitlab-ci, rubocop

I'm using:

Gitlab 7.11.2

Rails 3.2

Pronto 0.4.2

pronto-rubocop 0.4.4

And I'm having trouble setting up the script to run Rubocop on git commits. I want to use Pronto so only the changes are checked. I am not using GitLab to host so I am not sure how to proceed when I reach this point of the Pronto setup, https://github.com/mmozuras/pronto:

> Set the GITLAB_API_ENDPOINT environment variable to your API endpoint URL. If you are using Gitlab.com's hosted service your endpoint will be https://gitlab.com/api/v3. Set the GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN environment variable to your Gitlab private token which you can find in your account settings.
>
> Then just run it:
>
> GITLAB_API_ENDPOINT="https://gitlab.com/api/v3" GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN=token pronto run -f gitlab -c origin/master

Where do I run the last command?:

> GITLAB_API_ENDPOINT="https://gitlab.com/api/v3" GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN=token pronto run -f gitlab -c origin/master

I created a .gitlab-ci.yml file and it has:

```
before_script:
  - ruby -v
  - gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
  - bundle --without postgres
rubocop:
  script: bundle exec pronto run --index
```

But I can't tell if this is running.

I also did not set up GitlabFormatter as it is mentioned on the Pronto page, when I tried looking up information about it was vague and unhelpful to me.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**UPDATE

So I gave up on using .gitlab-ci.yml file route for now because the job on gitlab-ci worked. I figured out the endpoint and installed all the necessary requirements on the server and everything bundles correctly.

At the very end of the process, I run:

> GITLAB_API_ENDPOINT="https://gitlab.com/api/v3" GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN=token pronto run -f gitlab -c origin/master

But the URL it generates is incorrect and I cannot add comments to the commit:

> https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/10022%2Fname%2Fapp-name/repository/commits/ad87234..asdf87923/comments

I'm getting an

> (Gitlab::Error::NotFound)

and I looks like it is coming from this part of code:

```
 ../10022%2Fname%2Fapp-name/..
```

because I can see the JSON when I change it to

```
 ../name/app-name/..
```

Any idea on how to call the correct URL?

Answer (score 2):

Finally got this working.  I am hosting gitlab on my own server, the API endpoint will look up the correct project as long as you have "api/v3" at the end. It's when you specify projects that things can go wrong, you'll know this if you see errors similar to these:

```
"Project not found" --> don't specify the project

"Unauthorized" --> are you using the correct user token?
```

Finally, even after pronto is run and it tells you how many errors were found or how many comments left, it might not always show up on the commit BUT if you submit a merge request the rubocop comments will show up.

To have the gitlab build fail if there are style guide violations run pronto with the option:

```
--exit-code
```